# I am trying to have a container inside the footer. I am able to position it to the left and right but i am not sure why its not going into the middle

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

I am able to change the float to right and left and the effect apply but when i put in center it does not go there. I am trying to align the container to the center, Not sure when i am going wrong here. I am new to HTML and CSS and the enviorment i am running is sharepoint

```css
.footer {
clear:both;
font-family: 'McLaren', cursive;
background-color:black;
text-align:center;
height:50px;
padding-top: 10px;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Book {
  float:right;
  position:relative;
  width: 20%;
  padding:0px;
  height:40px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer">
  <div class="Book" style="background-color:Grey;">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to horizontally center a <div>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/how-to-horizontally-center-a-div)

Comment: Replace your css:  .footer { clear:both;  font-family: 'McLaren', cursive; background-color:black; text-align:center; height:50px; padding-top: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; } and .Book { width: 20%; background-color: grey; display: inline-block; position:relative; padding:0px; height:40px; }

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`float: right;`

Use

`margin: auto;`

Comment: I put it as margin: 0 auto; but nothing changed

Comment: I have never used sharepoint so all I can suggest is to try it without the "0".

Comment: Fixed it, I had to change the position to relative. Thanks for the help though